# Next.JS app (with Chakra UI) not full width on mobile devices

Tags: css, next.js, media-queries, width, chakra-ui

This one is giving me a headache..
Perhaps I'm just missing something silly, hope you guys can help.

The whole html element has a width of approximately 80% of the screen on mobile devices.

On a laptop, reducing the screen size does not replicate the problem. The html will be full size as expected.

Here's the link of the app so you can see by yourself : https://kaayo.vercel.app/

I tried debugging with android devtools and this is what it shows:

[image: this]

And finally, here's my chakraTheme.js:

```
global: {
      "html, body": {
        color: "gray.600",
        margin: "0",
        padding: "0",
        lineHeight: "tall",
        fontWeight: "400",
        backgroundColor: "bg.100",
      },
      body: { minHeight: "100vh" },
      "input:focus": {
        borderColor: "primary.200!important",
      },
      "a:hover": {
        textDecoration: "none",
      },
      ':focus:not(:focus-visible):not([role="dialog"]):not([role="menu"])': {
        boxShadow: "none !important",
      },
    },
```

If you need anything else just tell me.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This https://nimb.ws/i2CJIU turned into this: https://nimb.ws/oqjzPD `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` Try adding `initial-scale=1` that is all. Later you may want to adjust the padding of body or other elements since it is now set to 0, the elements would be touching the screen.

Comment: Works like a charm! Now I realize that's in the next documentation, I just missed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is probably box-sizing property. Try box-sizing:

```
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```